# How to plot line graph for wide dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataset looks like this:

```
id    x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5   ... x10000     Date     
1    40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33     2006-01-01 
2    35  35.75 36.5 26.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29     2007-01-01 
3    35  35.70 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29     2007-01-01 
4    40  31.50 23.5 24.5 26.5 25   ...  33     2016-01-01
 ... 
900  40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  23     2000-01-01
```

Here each row is a time series. I would like to visualise all time series using `matplotlib` with the column names as mark on `x axis`. How can I do it in one graph? What is the best way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try `df.set_index('Date').plot()`?

Comment: try @Chris method, but keep in mind you got like 10000+ columns so plotting might not going well.

Comment: Thank you @Chris @hunzter Will setting `'Date'` as the index make each row as a time series?

Comment: Can you define what makes _each row as a time series_?

Comment: @Chris columns `x0` to `x10000` are timestamps of 1min interval. For instance, I want to plot the values for `id 1` time series to see how `id 1` changes over time. Then plot for all id in one graph

Comment: Plotting for all `id` returned `ValueError: Image size of 368x151269 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.` I am trying with a single line...

Comment: I think it is just too much data for a single plot, unless you have important correlations between different ids. Imo the only way you can get something out of it is to first bin all data along the time axis, then try to create clusters of similar data to goup different ids in a single color. If you are very lucky you might be able to plot something meaningful..

Comment: Hi @Andrea thanks for the suggestion. Any thought on how I should bin the data? It was water temperature data in the pipe which experiences sharp rise and gradual decrease for each activation. Thank you

Comment: I'm sry but I'm afraid I can not help without handling the data and understanding the problem. There is no correct way of doing a plot, the most important thing when working on this kind of problems is to have in mind what you want to communicate with it. Sometimes you need to plot less to communicate more

Comment: @Andrea thank you for your advice. I will think about it:)